# Loading trained model to make prediction of single image

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch, multiclass-classification

I have trained a ResNet50 model on intel image multiclass classification task. The task is trying to predict an image whether it is a building a street or glacier etc. The model is succesfully trained and able to make prediction. I have save the model and trying to use the saved model on new image.
Here is the code on training

```
import os
import torch
import tarfile
import torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision.utils import make_grid
from torch.utils.data import random_split
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision.datasets.utils import download_url
import PIL
import PIL.Image
import numpy as np
transform_train=transforms.Compose([
                                    transforms.Resize((150,150)),
                                    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                    transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(),
                                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                                    transforms.Normalize((.5,.5,.5),(.5,.5,.5))
])
transform_test=transforms.Compose([
                                   transforms.Resize((150,150)),
                                   transforms.ToTensor(),
                                   transforms.Normalize((.5,.5,.5),(.5,.5,.5))
])
...
torch.save(model2.state_dict(),'/content/drive/MyDrive/saved_model/model_resnet.pth')
```

When I called the model in other files, I use similar image transformation, however it gives me an error, here is the code and the error

```
model = torch.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/saved_model/model_resnet.pth')
image=Image.open(Path('/content/drive/MyDrive/images/seg_pred/seg_pred/10004.jpg'))
transform_train=transforms.Compose([
                                    transforms.Resize((150,150)),
                                    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
                                    transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(),
                                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                                    transforms.Normalize((.5,.5,.5),(.5,.5,.5))
])
input = transform_train(image)

#input = input.view(1, 3, 150,150)

output = model(input)

prediction = int(torch.max(output.data, 1)[1].numpy())
print(prediction)
```

The error that gives me is

```
TypeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object is not callable
```

My pytorch version is
1.9.0+cu102

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the structure of the model first, it's similar to create `model2` on your training code, it can be like:

```
model = resnet()
```

Then load the saved state dict:

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/saved_model/model_resnet.pth'))
model.eval()
```

Ref:

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html

Comment: Thanks, I did model=models.resnet50(), model.load_state_dict(torch.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/saved_model/model_resnet.pth')). it gives me another error RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for ResNet:

Comment: I am trying this tutorial, https://www.kaggle.com/awadhi123/intel-multiclass-classification?scriptVersionId=37760533 and save the model, I would like to predict a new image data. Thanks for your help

Comment: @rickyfajrin93 you've modified the resnet model, load model first e.g. `mymodel = IntelCnnModelresnet()`, then load state_dict: `mymodel.load_state_dict(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question it's clear that you want to prediction on a new image. But you are trying to augment and get transform the image using `transform` which is not a proper way to get the prediction.

So as the code link you provided having plenty of code you can use them as in your code.

I am sharing the `fast.ai` and simple `TensorFlow code by which you can predict a new image and then be able to see the result.

```
img = open_image('any_image.jpg')
print(learn.predict(img)[0])
```

**OR you can try this function:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # visualization
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import tensorflow as tf # Deep Learning Framework
import pathlib
def pred_plot(file, model, class_names=class_names, image_size=(150, 150)):
    img = tf.io.read_file(file)
    img = tf.io.decode_image(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, size=image_size)
    
    pred_probs = model.predict(tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0))
    pred_class = class_names[pred_probs.argmax()]
    
    plt.imshow(img/225.)
    plt.title(f'Pred: {pred_class}')
    plt.axis(False);
```

pass any image and you will get the prediction with visilzation.

```
url ='dummy.jpg'
pred_plot(url, model=model_2, class_names=class_names)
```